# Purapedda shanthi

Tags: temple, death, priests

In Kerala temples like ananthapadmanabha, guruvayoor etc, there was a parapadda shanthi systems - where the priests we're forbidden to go outside the temple complex during the term. Even if it was emergency? Want to know what this emergency includes? What about death of family members?

Is it true that they were made to reduce their soothikam (asouchayam) period to 3 days?

I want to know more about the restrictions